# System.currentTimeMillis() behaving erroneously

Tags: java, android, datetime

I'm creating a text file with timestamps derived from the result of System.currentTimeMillis(). My algorithm is such:

1. Create file and record timestamp of creation
2. Save timestamp each time a button is pressed
3. Subtract file-creation timestamp from button-press timestamp
4. Write result to the file

For some odd reason, the timestamp of the file creation is usually greater (younger, more recent) than the timestamp of the button presses, which always  happen AFTER the file was created. This results in a negative value being returned from step 3.

What is causing this?

**FileCreationMenu.java**

```
    public class FileCreationMenu extends Fragment {
            public Button toggleRecordingButton;
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup    container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment_calibrator, container, false); 
                toggleRecordingButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.recordAudioToggle);
                toggleRecordingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        recordAudio = !recordAudio; //toggle audio recording on/off
                        if (recordAudio==true){
                            AudioRecorder.createFile(System.currentTimeMillis());  //generate file for new track if record is togged ON
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**AudioRecorder.java**

```
 public static void createFile(long time) {  //create file and record creation timeStamp
        recordingStartTime = time;
        myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "file.txt");  //save to external storage
        try {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void recordNote(long timeStamp){  //record timeStamps of notes
        String playedNote = (timeStamp+ "\n" );
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);
            fos.write(playedNote.getBytes());
            fos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   public static void playTrack(String fileName){   //playback Notes
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile.getPath());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String line;
        try {
            int i =0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {   //read each line of input file
                historicalTime[i] = Long.parseLong(line);  //store time current line's note was played 
                if (i==0){
                    timeStream[i] = (Long.parseLong(line) - recordingStartTime); //if first note, calculate wait based on file creation time
                }
                else{
                    timeStream[i] = (Long.parseLong(line) - historicalTime[i-1]); //otherwise, calculate wait as amount of time note was played after most recent preceding note 
                }
                i++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i=0; i<noteStream.length; i++){
            try {
                AudioRecorder.class.wait(timeStream[i]); //wait 
                //Play Note
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
public static void noteDetected(){
        if (FileCreationMenu.recordAudio == true){
            AudioRecorder.recordNote(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
```

Again, the problem is that recordingStartTime in AudioRecorder.java is often greater than the input parameter "timeStamp" to recordNote from the MainActivity. For example, in a recent debugging session recordingStartTime =1,450,573,093,044 while timeStamp=1,450,565,187,318.

What could be causing this seemingly impossible behavior?

Comment: Where do you call `noteDetected `?

Comment: Lots of static methods and functions there. Have youb checked recordingStartTime is set only once and onlynfrom within that one button? Can you share that write into file part?

Comment: @shhp noteDetected is a standalone method in the MainActivity that happens outside of onCreate(). There are a bunch of other factors for whether or not a note is detected so I did not bother to list them all here. I believe this is the only relevant part of code in that class for my question.

Comment: @Vince Emigh I'm not familiar with a Timestamp from the JDK, how do I use this and how does it differ from  System.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: @Jan Yes. I am sure that recordingStartTime is only set once on the provided line of code in AudioRecorder. What do you mean by "share that write into file part"? I'd be happy to provide more information to help us get to the bottom of this issue.

Comment: I don't see you ever writing recordingStartTime or doing calculations on that in your code. Also you don't seem to be closing Fileoutputstream in recordNote

Comment: I omitted the part where I do calculcations on recordingStartTime. I'll include it, check the edit to AudioRecorder.java above. I've never had any problems reading or writing the file with the code as is (no fos.close() call). I'm sure this is inefficient so I will add the call but I am fairly certain this has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Am I missing something? I can't see the code that writes your recordstarttime to your first line? Since your values differ by ~8k sec, could you also verify which of both values is likely to be correct? (Sry for answer, phone with weblogin instead of app)

Comment: @ChristianR. You don't see it because recordStartTime is never written to my file. recordStartTime is only used on the first iteration of playTrack(). The problem is recordStartTime  is greater than the button press timeStamps for the first few iterations of playTrack(), as detailed in my example at the bottom of my question. This causes the value stored in timeStream[i] (in playTrack) to be negative when i=0. Since recordStartTime is created before the button is pressed my intuition tells me that recordStartTime is wrong, as it should always be smaller than any button timeStamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
myFile.createNewFile();
```

The JavaDoc for this method says

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname **if and only if** a file with this name does not yet exist

So every time you try to start a new recording you are actually reusing the same file (with timestamps from long ago) but record a new recordStartTime.

If you want to remove the old file first you will have to write

```
myFile.delete();
myFile.createNewFile();
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for the answer, I'm testing the solution. If it works you get the check.